# Link Tables - Code First - Entity Framework - Table-Mapping

Tags: ef-code-first, fluent-interface, data-annotations

I asked a related question previously on this forum. This question outlines the steps I have taken, different things I have tried and errors I have encountered. It might help someone.

Considering a mapping to a structure that involves a link table, it seems to me there is a quirk with Code First, Link Tables and TPH or perhaps just a lack of transparency.

I created a derived class with a [Table("")] attribute to map objects to the following sort of table structures:

```
(Case 1) Employees -> Attributes -> AttributeTypes

(Case 2) Employees -> EmployeeAttributeLink -> Attributes -> AttributeTypes
```

In the former case i achieved the results i wanted for TPH querying and saving. (I used data annotation attributes along with fluent api to map the derived classes to the correct discriminator id column).

However, in the second case I got this error:
'The entity types A and B cannot share table B because they are not in the same type hierarchy [OR] do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them. Need to have a 1-1 correspondence'

When I looked at the names of the tables that it was trying to map types to I could see it was confused. However I could not figure out what I was doing wrong as I had used the correct table mapping attribute above the inheriting classes (I didn't define all the sub types that could come from the discriminator - does that matter?).

I introduced some FK attributes trying to address the second part of the [OR]  in the error message. This led me to new problems i.e. unable to determine principal/dependant... Then I tried to use the [InverseProperty] attributes... And then I started pulling my hair out.

Now, rolling back and removing the attributes, I decided not to rely on [Table("")] attribute and map the type to the table using the fluent api. This seems to work.

My question is: Why is it that the behaviour of the [Table("") ] attribute and the ToTable function on the fluent API behave differently? I would have thought they are interchangeable

Thanks